# What Shimano microspline rear wheel hub would fit my 26in Mavic Cross ride wheels?

Tags: wheels, cassette, disc-brake, hub

Title.

I purchased a new Deore 1x12 groupset without realising I would need to change the rear hub to fit the new microspline Shimano introduced a couple of years ago.

What would the Shimano rear wheel hub product be to fit my specifications?

I also currently have a 140 rear brake disc that I don't want to replace but will if required to.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Mavic has different families for their hubs, so 'CrossRide' is not accurate enough to give an answer, as it changes over years and entry level hubs may not be the same as the higher end ones.

<strike>If you look at the specifications of your hub and see that it is ID360 or ITS-4: you can just replace the freehub body without having to unmount the rear hub.</strike>

https://www.mavic.com/en-gb/freehub-body-oc0675.html

EDIT: I mixed up CrossRide and CrossMax. CrossRide is the entry level range of Mavic and is not compatible with the MicroSpline freehub bodies I mentioned.

So the options are limited: the easiest is the solution mentioned by Weiwen Ng: using a non-shimano 12 speed 11/51 cassette. Otherwise, I'm afraid that the only solution is to build a new wheel. The only rear hub with quick release I'm aware of is the Shimano FH-MT401 (OLD 135mm) or FH-MT401-B (OLD 141mm, but that's unlikely), but it won't work with your current rim: Mavic uses 24 spokes and the Shimano hub is only available for 28/32/36 spokes.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with Mavic's offerings, so I shall not contradict Renaud's answer. I will offer a possible alternative: some third party manufacturers like Sunrace make 12s MTB cassettes that fit on Hyperglide freehub bodies. These cassettes will only start at 11t because the HG freehub's diameter is physically too large to take a 10t cassette. Hence, this option affects your gear range.

Also, you might expect third party cassettes to have less good shifting than Shimano 12s cassettes. The phrase "less good" is clunky but intentional: many riders may perceive the shifting as fine in an absolute sense. I have used a third-party cassette with 11s Shimano road before and I thought I could perceive a small difference vs. stock Shimano.

Comment: There is definitely a difference in speed and smoothness of shifts between, say, a SunRace hyperglide cassette and a Shimano offering.  Brand of chain too. At 9 speed I varied between KMC, Shimano and SRAM (I'm exclusively Shimano drivetrain), at 10 speed I much preferred Shimano HG95's, now at 11s, I feel I must have Shimano, and apparently when I move to 12 cogs, Shimano becomes mandatory (within their drivetrain).

Comment: The difference in smoothness is especially visible with their 12-speed offering, for which Shimano introduced Hyperglide+. But from I understood, it's recommended to not use a shimano chain if not using a shimano cassette.

Comment: @Renaud With 11s and earlier, I'd have no hesitation about using a Shimano chain on any cassette if I wanted to. With 12s, I think you're right and the inner links or some other parts may be shaped differently than prior chains. Thus, if you're on a third-party 12s cassette, it may be best not to use a Shimano chain.