# Can I put a different manufacturer’s freehub body on my hub?

Tags: hub, freehub

Can I replace my Mavic Cross One freehub body with a non-Mavic one? I want to switch to Shimano microspline.

Comment: Welcome to Stack exchange. I edited this post to improve clarity. Please feel free to revert it if the meaning of your question was changed.

Comment: Related: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/82544

Answer (score 9):

There are two parts to this question.

- Generally, you cannot swap freehub bodies between manufacturers. There are some exceptions to this (some hub manufacturers use DT Swiss hub mechanisms, so there probably is compatibility there). Looking at [Mavic's freehub body](https://www.mavic.com/en-us/freehub-body-oc0675.html) and [Shimano's](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0807/5697/products/shimfhb3c_5000x.jpg?v=1427561813), they have very different shapes where they meet the hub shell, so I would expect them to be incompatible. The freehub body is a part of the freewheeling mechanism, and there are two popular designs for these (pawls and sawtooth ring gears), with numerous variations on each design. The body needs to fit its exact design.
- Usually, a single manufacturer will offer the same hub shell with different freehub bodies (microspline, Campagnolo, etc), and you *can* swap freehub bodies as long as you stay with the same manufacturer. This may not always be true, especially if the manufacturer has changed the freewheeling mechanism in their hubs since you bought your hub and they have no more old stock.

Comment: Another very minor point: not all manufacturers offer every freehub standard. Generally, everyone will offer the Shimano standards, and most people offer the SRAM standards. Shimano’s own factory wheel sets only offer Shimano bodies, whereas Campagnolo/Fulcrum offer everyone else’s.

Comment: Also worth noting that Mavic does offer a Microspline freehub body, though it may be newer thatn your wheels, so you'd have to double check the compatibility with your the wheels you own. https://www.mavic.com/en-us/freehub-body-oc0675.html

Answer (score 4):

If your wheel has a ITS4 based hub body you can’t get a Mavic microspline freehub to replace it.

I’ve seen some 3rd party ITS4 microspline hub bodies pop up on AliExpress. YMMV

If you have the newer ID360 based hubs then Mavic does have a microspline hub body.

https://www.cyclefastusa.com/mavic-microspline-mtb-freewheel-body-id360/0501225

**EDIT**

Seems the CrossOne uses the earlier FTS-X type bodies.

https://www.mavicparts.com/collections/mavic-freehubs/products/mavic-shimano-sram-freehub-body-for-mountain-m40580

Pretty much zero chance of finding a microspline body for that.

And yes, as others have mentioned manufacturers mostly use proprietary interfaces for their freehub bodies and generally can’t be mixed and matched.

Answer (score -1):

Not you can't different hub manufacturer has different freehub mechanism,99% of them can't be exchange,just small number of hubs they adopt the exact same of mechanism and same sizes as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  This would be a better answer (and attract votes) if you were specific about some of the incompatibilities and make particular note of Mavic Cross One, and adapting to Microspline.  This might be correct in general, but you should establish this case doesn't fall into the 1% you say might be compatible.